# Insert id, name of column and value into a Table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a result table with one row and some columns:

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | column6 | column7 | column8 | column9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.4 | 2.2 | 3.4 | 6.57 | 5.6 | 9.7 | 67.6 | 3.4 | 5.9 |

I have a table like:

```
DECLARE @TTable TABLE(
 ID INT,
 Name VARCHAR(100),
 value FLOAT 
)
```

I want to have something like

| ID | Name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | column1 | 1.4 |
| 2 | column2 | 2.2 |
| 3 | column3 | 3.4 |
| 4 | column4 | 6.57 |
| 5 | column5 | 5.6 |
| 6 | column6 | 9.7 |
| 7 | column7 | 67.6 |
| 8 | column8 | 3.4 |
| 9 | column9 | 5.9 |

So I am doing something like:

```
INSERT @TTable   
SELECT [id]  = ORDINAL_POSITION,  
[Name] = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ORIGINALTABLE' ORDER BY id
```

this results with 2 fields '`id`', and '`Name`' of column, but How would you add the `value` field?

If I add a `SELECT` to the query:

```
INSERT @TTable   
SELECT [id]  = ORDINAL_POSITION,  
[Name] = COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ORIGINALTABLE' ORDER BY id,  [value] = ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2008, the you can use `UNPIVOT` and dynamic SQL so you don't have to write every column on your own (Before using dynamic SQL take a look at this [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)). Try this:

**UPDATED after comments**

```
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)='', @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @CastColumns NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT  @Columns = @Columns + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ',',
        @CastColumns = @CastColumns+CASE WHEN data_type <> 'float' THEN
        'CAST('+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+' AS FLOAT) AS '+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) ELSE
        QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) END+','
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YourTable' 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SET @Columns = LEFT(@Columns,LEN(@Columns)-1)
SET @CastColumns = LEFT(@CastColumns,LEN(@CastColumns)-1)

SET @Query = '
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CO.Ordinal_Position) Id, ColumnName, Value
FROM (SELECT '+@CastColumns+' FROM YourTable) AS P
UNPIVOT(value FOR ColumnName IN ('+@Columns+')) AS UC
JOIN (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''YourTable'') CO
ON ColumnName = CO.COLUMN_NAME
'

INSERT INTO @TTABLE
EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Ok, now I changed the query so it does a `CAST` to FLOAT over the columns that are not already FLOAT. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: The type of column "column2" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the ´UNPIVOT´ list.

Comment: @darkcminor: yeah, the query above assumes that all your original columns are of the same data type, if not, then you have to do a `CAST` or `CONVERT` on the `UNPIVOT`

Comment: so if a field is `float`, I do `UNPIVOT(Cast(value as float) FOR ColumnName IN ('+@Columns+'))`  ?? or as `varchar`??, is it correct the syntax?

Comment: It works great, only one more question...    If There is a column named `a` at the very end of the original table (last column)    How do you tell the query not to order by column name, instead by Ordinal Position, because as `a` is first than `column1` at the moment the query orders, it puts first `a` and not last

Comment: @darkcminor: I added the `ORDER` by ordinal_position on the query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a cross-tab query to transform from a row with many columns to a number of rows with a couple of columns, good example [in this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/).  Or in [Celko's fantastic Sql For Smarties Book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hi9fMnOoRtAC&pg=PA542&lpg=PA542&dq=cross+tab+query+celko&source=bl&ots=tsdV-aV7Tr&sig=Rd-qUNm8pCzPq_VCOCU9vhHKCJM&hl=en&ei=W9lrTeelB82BhQebif3xDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Basically you do a series of case statements that transform the table by pivoting it on an axis.